# How to exclude an AD OU from importing groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a piece of software that imports groups from certain OU's within AD. I have an OU that has four nested OU's within it and I only want to import from three of these. How do I exclude the one OU from importing?

There is the option within the software to use what's called a filter string, which I have been using to manually type in the filter to exclude this one OU from importing. The filter clearly isn't correct as the job imports from all of the OU's.

I want to exclude the UAT OU from importing so I tried the following filter:

```
(&(objectClass=Group)(!(ou:cn:=*_UAT)))
```

All groups within the UAT OU end in _UAT, which is why I tried the above filter. The job successfully ran but imported from all four OU's.

I want the import to only import AD groups from three of the four OU's I have nested within the Application OU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this just in the query. There is no attribute called `ou`, which is why the filter you tried didn't work.

Starting in Windows Server 2012, there is an attribute called `msDS-parentdistname`, which has the `distinguishedName` of the OU, but it is a constructed attribute, meaning it's not actually stored; it's constructed at the time it is requested. That means you can't use it in a query.

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Change the search scope to "single level" so it does not search any nested OUs. You would have to search each of the three OUs separately this way.
2. Get *all* the results, and remove the unwanted results after the search. Check if the `distinguishedName` contains the name of the unwanted OU and, if so, discard it.